# Running XSLT on servers?

Tags: html, xml

Currently I am working on a project for a client that compares the difference between two XML files, generates an XML that lists the differences (i.e. if a part in an inventory was `<Added>, <Deleted>, or <Modified>`) and displays a report in HTML.

I have three transforms that basically transform large vendor-specific XML files to simple generic XML files (schema defined).  These generic XML files are then transformed into one generic XML file that shows the differences and then that is transformed to a report.html for display for the user.

Presently for testing, I invoke a .bat file to run all three transforms (using Saxon8.jar).  My question is, is it possible to put these transforms on a server and create a HTML page with a one-click action that will let the user upload the vendor-specific XML files, transform them, and display the generated HTML file to the user?

Comment: I think this belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ . Besides that the answer is yes...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified whether you'll be using php, java or ASP.NET, however, the functionality you're looking for is possible in all three cases. Your backend web app should have the necesssary mechanism to accept the file uploaded by the user, save it in some work folder, run the necessary transformation using your chosen language, Jave, C#, php etc. and then write back the HTML.

Comment: Sorry about that, I would be using Java

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes.

To do it you'd typically use some server-side technology (php, ruby, java) to perform the transforms.

[But browser-side XSLT is possible, too.](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Browser-Side_XSLT)

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Cocoon](http://cocoon.apache.org/) is a powerful XML processing engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing this one job, then coding a Java servlet to do it is not too difficult. If you're doing lots of similar things, a framework like Cocoon or Orbeon will save you effort in the long run.